# How to remove specific columns when doing a logistic regression on all variables

Tags: r

I would like to perform a logistic regression on all variables but two in a large data frame.How can i ask r to refer to all variable except those two without creating a new data frame.
for example:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " female  apcalc    admit       num
  0        0        0         7
  0        0        1         1
  0        1        0         3
  0        1        1         7
  1        0        0         5
  1        0        1         1
  1        1        0         0
  1        1        1         6", header = TRUE)
```

I have this line of code :

```
Model1 <- glm(admit ~.,data=dat,family = 'binomial')
```

and i want to take out "female" and "apcalc". Can I do it in this single line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the model statement to just include the variables you want.  I think all three lines below return the same estimates:

```
# remove the variable(s) you do not want

summary(glm(admit ~ . - female - apcalc, data=dat, family = 'binomial'))

# specify the variable(s) you do want

summary(glm(admit ~ num, data=dat, family = 'binomial'))

# remove the variable(s) you do not want

summary(glm(admit ~ I(0 * female) + I(0 * apcalc) + num, data=dat, family = 'binomial'))
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

If you want to remove those columns for analysis, then either subset the data before running the model, or inside the `glm` call.  Keep in mind the latter will slow the call to `gml` for larger data sets.

```
> dat2 <- dat[!names(dat) %in% c("female", "apcalc")]
  admit num
1     0   7
2     1   1
3     0   3
4     1   7
5     0   5
6     1   1
7     0   0
8     1   6

> glm(admit ~., data = dat2, family = 'binomial')
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you want to extract only the coefficients for `female` and `apcalc`, then

```
> glm(admit ~.,data=dat,family = 'binomial')$coef[c("female", "apcalc")]
```

Comment: I notice a difference in AIC after removing the variables before training the model and when I remove the variables within glm. Is there a reason for this?